# $m(x) := \inf\{f(t): t \in [a, x)\}$ and $M(x) := \sup\{f(t): t \in [a, x)\}$ . Prove $m$ and $M$ are continuous from left on $(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$. Define $m(x) = \inf\{f(t): t \in [a, x)\}$ and $M(x) = \sup\{f(t): t \in [a, x)\}$ . Prove that $m$ and  $M$ are continuous from left on $(a,b)$

Could anyone help me please in solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}$ increase to $x$. If $\epsilon >0$ then there exists $y \in [a,x)$ such that $f(y) < m(x)+\epsilon$. Since $y <x$ we have $y<x_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large so $m(x_n) \leq f(y)< m(x)+\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Also, $m(x) \leq m(x_n)$ for all $n$. This proves that $m(x_n) \to m(x)$. The argument for $M(x)$ is similar. You can also prove left continuity of $M$ using that of $m$ by changing $f$ to $-f$.

Comment: Could you describe in words what you are doing please?

Comment: what is the importance of the given that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Why you choosed $\{x_{n}\}$ to increase to x, what if it decreases?

Comment: $f$ bounded makes $m$ and $M$ real valued.

Comment: so you have proved by this that m is continuous from left .... correct?

Comment: A function $g$ is continuous from the left at $a$ if $g(x_n) \to g(a)$ for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ increasing to $a$. We are asked to prove continuity from the left. We can give counterexamples to show that $m$ and $M$ need not be continuity from the right.

Comment: So the continuity from right definition will be the same except that every sequence is decreasing to x .... correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It looks strange for me the the infimum anf supremum of the function both are continuous from left..... do you have any justification for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84321/discussion-between-kavi-rama-murthy-and-happy).

Comment: How this leads to that lim m(x_{n}) = m(x)?

Comment: The problem is that I am leaving my home now.

Comment: what property of inf and supremum lead me to use -f instead of f incase of proving $M$ case?

Comment: Hey Kavi I am not sure how to complete the case for $M$, could you please provide more details?